# Dynamically Calculate and display Total Number of list items in a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, nested-lists

I am using lists in my sidebar, and I want to display a label number of how many items are in that list.

I have created a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/WRVgW/ to demonstrate the list and what I am trying to achieve. I am sure this is achievable with Jquery but I am not sure how and looking for some guidance.

In my example I have hardcoded in the number `34` where I want the number to be dynamically generated based on the list below it.

My HTML Code which I commented is pasted below but maybe easier to see it in context with the result in the http://jsfiddle.net/WRVgW/

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul class="sidebarSections">
    <li class="submenu">
    <a href="#"><span>Design Projects</span><!--This is the name of the project-->
    <span class="label">34</span></a><!--This is the number which I want to display the number of li items below dynamically (should be 3)-->
        <ul>
            <li><a>Project x</a></li>
            <li><a>Project y</a></li>
            <li><a>Project z</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="submenu">
    <a href="#"><span>Tech Projects</span><!--This is the name of the project-->
    <span class="label">34</span></a><!--This is the number which I want to display the number of li items below dynamically (should be 5)-->
        <ul>
            <li><a>Project x</a></li>
            <li><a>Project y</a></li>
            <li><a>Project z</a></li>
            <li><a>Project y</a></li>
            <li><a>Project z</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="submenu">
    <a href="#"><span>IA Projects</span><!--This is the name of the project-->
    <span class="label">34</span></a><!--This is the number which I want to display the number of li items below dynamically (should be 7)-->
        <ul>
            <li><a>Project x</a></li>
            <li><a>Project y</a></li>
            <li><a>Project z</a></li>
            <li><a>Project y</a></li>
            <li><a>Project z</a></li>
            <li><a>Project y</a></li>
            <li><a>Project z</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
$(".submenu .label").text(function() {
  return $(this).closest(".submenu").find("li").length;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/WRVgW/1/

Comment: thanks for the answer, I just had one follow up. Would it be possible to calculate the number on the fly as I drag and drop items into the list. I made an update to your example here http://jsfiddle.net/WRVgW/2/ - you can see you can drag the `<li>` items between lists but the number does not update obviously. was wondering if possible

Comment: To make the code available to be called multiple times, wrap it in a named function. Then call that function wherever it is needed. The only proviso is that the function must, as always, be within scope.

Comment: @Redwall You can use `update` event for `sortable`: http://jsfiddle.net/WRVgW/4/.

Comment: awesome thanks so much for all your help...I guess only thing is the numbers say 34 (the hardcoded figure) until I make the first drag and drop. I guess the update happens then. Is there a way to fire an update when the HTML loads so I can have the correct numbers in there from the start?

Answer (score 0):

code (javascript)  & id your uls

```
var ul = document.getElementById("myul");
var liNodes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < ul.childNodes.length; i++) {
  if (ul.childNodes[i].nodeName == "LI") {
    liNodes.push(ul.childNodes[i]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
$('.sidebarSections ul').each(function(){
    var liCount = $(this).find('li').length;
    $(this).closest('.submenu').find('span.label').text(liCount);
});
```